# PHP DateTime Timezones - Constructor vs Setter method

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone

When using the PHP `DateTime` class and try to set a `DateTimeZone` I get different results depending on how I set it: using the `DateTime::__construct` or using the `DateTime::setTimezone` method.

here is an example:

```
$date = '2014-08-01'

$dateTimeOne = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
echo $dateTimeOne->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP'); 
// 2014-08-01T00:00:00-07:00

$dateTimeTwo = new DateTime($date);
$dateTimeTwo->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
echo $dateTimeTwo->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP'); 
// 2014-07-31T17:00:00-07:00
```

See also http://3v4l.org/LrZfM

I have looked around and have not found an adequate explanation that addresses these particular behavior other than the following comment in the [php docs: datetime.settimezone](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php#94784) and the book [php|architect's Guide to Date and Time Programming: Dealing with Timezones - DateTimeZone](http://www.phparch.com/books/phparchitects-guide-to-date-and-time-programming/).

The comment states that the `DateTime::setTimezone` method will change the timezone for a particular point in time (a time stamp) but the Unix time stamp remains unchanged.

In the other hand the `DateTime::__construct` DateTimeZone parameter is used to "overwrite the current default timezone with a user defined one" [Chapter 3: Dealing with Timezones - DateTimeZone](http://www.phparch.com/books/phparchitects-guide-to-date-and-time-programming/).

Other than these there isn't much on the subject (that I was able to find).

This is what I would like to know:

- Further explanation of these two ways to set the timezones
- When should I use the `DateTime::__construct` to set the timezone
- When should I use the `DateTime::setTimezone` to set the timezone
- A clear example of using one vs the other or how to using them in conjunction

Comment: Having a timezone in the constructor means that `$date` is in that timezone; setting a timezone moves the date according to the difference between the timezone at construction and the given one.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal behaviour.

When you don't specify the timezone in the constructor, the default timezone is used, i.e what was set using date_default_timezone_set().

When you then call:

```
$dateTimeTwo->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
```

It moves the date set in the default timezone into the new timezone.

---

1) (constructor) set date in 'America/Los_Angeles'
2) (setter) set date in default timezone, move date to 'America/Los_Angeles'

---

Your default timezone was probably UTC or something close. You told the computer to set 2014-08-01 at UTC. You then asked to switch to the 'America/Los_Angeles' timezone which is 7 hours earlier thus by changing the date to 2014-07-31 at 17:00.