# Correctly format times between client (javascript) and the server (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, date, datetime

I have a date object in javascript that goes as follows:

```
var date = 2014-12-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

And if I do:

```
var date = new Date(date);
date.setUTCMonth(date.getUTCMonth()+1);
```

Then the `toISOString()` method shows the expected value:

> 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

But when I send that date time string through a POST to a PHP script and parse it back to a date using the `DateTime` class, I get this:

> 2014-12-31 19:00:00 -0500

I have tried setting the timezone using the `DateTimeZone` class and setting the timezone to my own and UTC without luck:

```
new DateTime($_POST['DateTime'],new DateTimeZone('America/Mexico_City'));
new DateTime($_POST['DateTime'],new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

Is there a way to set the timezone in javascript, using the `Date` class? Is there another way to work around this? I have small if not zero experience at all dealing with timezones.

**Update**:

Here's my ISO-formatted time string as per the `toISOString()` method (javascript):

> 2014-09-01T00:00:00.000Z

And here are the contents of my `$_POST` var as per `print_r()`:

```
Array (
    [DateTime] => 2014-09-01T00:00:00.000Z
)
```

Here's the output of my formatter function, using the `'%c'` format (es_MX locale):

> dom 31 ago 2014 19:00:00 CDT

And the mentioned formatter function:

```
function formatDate($date) {
    return utf8_encode(strftime('%c', $date->getTimestamp()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think when you send the date-string, it's somehow in different format. At least when I tested this, it works as expected:

```
$a = new DateTime('2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z');
echo $a->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Outputs '2015-01-01 00:00:00'
```

[Demo here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c90a8824ac411fd0a20023d81728d727522b281f).

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are getting is that when you use the following format

```
$date = '2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z';
```

You are specifying a timezone.

Notice the "**Z**" at the end of your date, using it is the equivalent of "[nautical timezone (GMT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)"

Therefore when you try to run this code, you will get the exact same date which is not what you expect even when you have specified the `DateTimeZone` as a constructor parameter.

```
$dateTime = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone('America/Mexico_City')); 
echo $dateTime->format('c'). "\n"; // 2015-01-01T00:00:00+00:00

$dateTime = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone('UTC')); 
echo $dateTime->format('c'). "\n"; //2015-01-01T00:00:00+00:00
```

This is expected PHP behavior and is documented in the `DateTime::__construct` [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) under the `$timezone` parameter:

> Note:
>
> The $timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored when the
>   $time parameter either is a UNIX timestamp (e.g. @946684800) or
>   specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00).

**In your case you are specifying a timezone directly with in your date (the "*Z*") and this is why the DateTimeZone object is ignored.**

To avoid this and set a custom time zone either set it in the date time string or get rid of the Z.:

```
$date = '2015-01-01T00:00:00.000';
$dateTime = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone('America/Mexico_City'));
echo $dateTime->format('c'). "\n"; // 2015-01-01T00:00:00-06:00

$dateTime = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone('UTC')); 
echo $dateTime->format('c'). "\n"; // 2015-01-01T00:00:00+00:00

$date = '2015-01-01T00:00:00.000 America/Mexico_City';
$dateTime = new DateTime($date);
echo $dateTime->format('c'). "\n"; //2015-01-01T00:00:00-06:00
```

See the code working for different versions of PHP here: [Demo](http://3v4l.org/YStcm)

Also take a look at this related question I asked recently: [PHP DateTime Timezones - Constructor vs Setter method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25658539/php-datetime-timezones-constructor-vs-setter-method)

Comment: The problem is not that I'm getting the Z-zone time, but rather a -0500 time and I want a Z-zone time.

Comment: Can you please specify what you get from `$_POST['DateTime']`?

Comment: Also take a look at the output in the code provided here: http://3v4l.org/0dTRW. If you are not getting a timezone back you should use the `new DateTimeZone('UTC')` IN THE CONSTRUCTOR ONLY and not use the `DateTime::setTimezone()` method as you will get different results see: http://3v4l.org/8Zd1Y. In the constructor it will ONLY change the timezone, in the method it will change the time (h:m) and timezone to represent the objects current date-time in a different timezone. See the related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25658539/php-datetime-timezones-constructor-vs-setter-method

Comment: The exact same string that the toISOString() method returns in my JavaScript algorithm, i.e. '2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'

Comment: Right, but once you submit your request and the PHP server handles the request, what is the content of the value in $_POST['DateTime']? It doesn't make sense that if you use that same string "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" and set the timezone in the constructor as UTC you will get the date "2014-12-31 19:00:00 -0500" which has a time offset of -5; you must not be using the correct value, or you are setting the timezone using the `DateTime::setTimezone`. If you look at the following Demo http://3v4l.org/YStcm you will see the functionality is the same for all versions of PHP  5.2.0 - 5.6.0.

Comment: Can you please post all of your code? Using the following demo http://3v4l.org/GCjpV I get this: `Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 2015` which is what I expect to see.